# switch template in a view on click

Tags: backbone.js

I want a view with summary and details div, initally I will show summary  which has a button details, click on the detail I am replacing view template  and call   render function  , is this right way to switch templates or is there a better way.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var viewTemplate= {
    name:'#template1'
}

var ContentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#content'),
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        var template = _.template($(viewTemplate.name).html());
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
    },
    events:{
        "click #showMore": "showMore",
        "click #showLess": "showLess"

    },
    showMore:  function(){
        viewTemplate.name='#template2';
        this.render();
        console.log(viewTemplate.name);
    },
    showLess:function(){
        viewTemplate.name='#template1';
        console.log(viewTemplate.name);
        this.render();
    }
});

var appView = new ContentView();
```

Answer (score 0):

have you considered adding a state property to your view? setting the state by changes or events in you application.

you render function can than render the correct view depending on states. each case can have its own template. seems easier to maintain.